# XAMPP can't see virtual host

Tags: apache, xampp, moodle

I am trying to create virtual host with xampp but it seems my apache configuration can't read host I created.
Every single time when I'm going to moodle36.dev/moodle/install.php in my browser it's reading xampp/htdocs/moodle instead of moodle from vhosts

That's my htttpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *80
...
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/vhosts/moodle36.devel"
    ServerName moodle36.dev
    ServerAlias www.moodle36.dev

    <Directory "C:/xampp/vhosts/moodle36.devel">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

That's httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride all
    Allow from all
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
</Directory> 
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
...
</Directory/>
```

I uncomented

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

and System32/drivers/etc/hosts

```
    127.0.0.1       moodle36.dev
```

I'm completly stuck and i would apreciatte any kind of help.

Comment: after change configuration you need to restart the server

Comment: I did it many times. I also tried runing control panel as administrator

Answer (score 0):

It might be because .dev is an existing top level domain.

Try .localhost or something that isn't in this list:

https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/tlds-2012-02-25-en

Comment: I just changed .dev to .localhost but it still doesn't work
Still reading htdocs instead of DocumentRoot